# laplace transform and conditioning

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, laplace-transform

Consider the continuous random variables $X, Z$ and $Y$. $Y = X + Z$. X and Z are independent. With probability $p$, $Z \sim X$, and with probability $1-p$, $Z = 0$.

My question is why I cannot get $Y = X + pX$?

What is the laplace transform of $Y$. I think it should be $\tilde{Y}(s) = p\tilde{X}(s)^2 + q\tilde{X}(s)$ but I am not sure.

Comment: $Y=2X$ or $Y=X$ not $X+pX$.  And it is not clear whether $Z=0$ is independent of $X$

Comment: Yes, they are independent. Could you explain why I cannot say $Y = X + p X$ or $Y = X_1 + p X_2$ where $X_1, X_2 \sim X$.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the laplace transform of $Y$. I think it should be $\tilde{Y}(s) = p\tilde{X}(s)^2 + q\tilde{X}(s)$ but I am not sure.

It is not; although the correct expression *looks* similar.

---

As Henry commented, for any given *non-zero* value for $X$, the value for $Y$ shall be either $X$ or $2X$ at probabilities of $(1-p)$ and $p$ respectively.   It will never be $(1+p)X$ … unless $p=1$ or $p=0$.

Now, the *conditional expectation* for $Y$ given $X$ shall be: $\mathsf E(Y\mid X)=(1+p)\,X$.  So indeed we obviously have:  $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y)&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))\\&=\mathsf E(pX+(1-p)X)\\&=(1+p)\,\mathsf E(X)\end{align}$$

---

However, you actually wish to evaluate $\tilde Y(s)$, the Laplace transform of $f_{\small Y}$ over its support; that is: $\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{-sY})$.  Still, you *can* find this in a similar manner:

$$\begin{align}\tilde Y(s)&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{-sY})\\&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{-sY}\mid X))\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

---

> Note $\tilde X(s)=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{-sX})$, so therefore $\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{-2sX})=\tilde X(2s)$.

Comment: What if X and Z are independent? Then $Y = X + X$ or $Y = X$ instead of $Y = 2X$ or $Y = X$. Then $\tilde{Y}(s) = p\tilde{(X + X)}(s) + q \tilde{X}(s) = p\tilde{X}(s)^2 + q\tilde{X}(s)$?

Comment: @oneuser $Z$ is always dependent on $X$ by its definition, and further, it is always true that $X+X=2X$ (as $X$ *cannot* be independent of $X$).  Also...$$\begin{align}\mathcal L_{f_{\small 2X}}(s)&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{-s(2X)})&&=\int_\Bbb R f_{\small 2X}(z)\mathrm e^{-s\,z}~\mathrm d z\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{-(2s)X})&&=\int_\Bbb R f_X(x)\mathrm e^{-2s\,x}\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\mathcal L_{f_{\small X}}(2s)\end{align}$$

Comment: When $U$ and $V$ are independent and identically distributed, the Laplace transformation of their sum is the square of the Laplace transform of $U$. $$\begin{align}\mathcal L_{f_{\small U+V}}(s)&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{-s(U+V)})\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{-sU}\,\mathrm e^{-sV})\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{-sU})\,\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{-sV})&&\text{because they are independent}\\[1ex]&=\mathcal L_{f_{\small U}}(s)^2\end{align}$$ However, the Laplace transform of the sum of $U$ and *itself* is not, because $U$ is *not* independent of itself.

Comment: I am sorry that I may mistake you since Z is not X. It's with probability $p$, Z take the same distribution as X and with probability $1-p$, Z takes 0. So Z is independent of X. May be s I should use $X_1$ and $X_2$.